# AvoidDuplicateLiterals pmd error for @MethodSource

Tags: java, junit, pmd

I am getting AvoidDuplicateLiterals pmd violation for using reference "abc" multiple times in different Method source.

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("abc")
public void someTestMethod(final    String endpoint) throws Exception {
// Rest of the code
}

private static Stream<String>    abc() {
// Rest of the code
}
```

I stored the "abc" reference in a variable like
private static final VAR_ABC = "abc" and put it in the Methodsource like @MethodSource(VAR_ABC)
but it didn't work.
Is there any way to resolve it without suppressing?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property "skipAnnotations" to true:

```xml
<rule ref="category/java/errorprone.xml/AvoidDuplicateLiterals">
    <properties>
        <property name="skipAnnotations" value="true" />
    </properties>
</rule>
```

See the full documentation of the rule here: https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_java_errorprone.html#avoidduplicateliterals
The the documentation on how to create a custom ruleset: https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_making_rulesets.html